# csv change order of the columns

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack, servicestack-text

I am currently using ServiceStack.Text to serialize CSV from a list of objects.
I have a model:

```
public class UploadDocument
{

[DataMember(Name = "Patient")]
public string Patient { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Patient First Name")]
public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Patient Last Name")]
public string PatientLastName { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

The result is:

```
Patient,    Patient First Name, Patient Last Name,  Email
XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,              nwerwer@yahoo.com,    
XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,              nwerwerwe@yahoo.com,    
XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,              nwerwe@yahoo.com,
```

However, for another report I need to change the order of the csv and return:

```
Email,               Patient,    Patient First Name, Patient Last Name,  
nwerwer@yahoo.com,   XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,                  
nwerwerwe@yahoo.com, XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,                  
nwerwe@yahoo.com,    XXX,        YYY,                ZZZZZ,
```

Is there a way to do that avoiding create a new model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the order option.
Ex:
[DataMember(Order = 0)]

the documentation is at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-order

Comment: I tried this solution, without luck. May I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's some examples of setting Custom Headers in [CustomHeaderTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/CsvTests/CustomHeaderTests.cs) where you can override the CSV Headers that are serialized. Note: this is static configuration that should be initialized once on Startup as it's not ThreadSafe to mutate at runtime.

But I'd personally define a separate model with the order and number of headers you want, you shouldn't think of it as duplicating code, your declaratively defining the structure you want in each use-case which is more maintainable then modifying serialization implementation at runtime.

To map between the models you can use ServiceStack's [AutoMapping Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping), e.g:

```
var report2 = report1.ConvertTo<List<Report2Document>>();
```

Another solution that avoids defining a model is to [convert the model to an Object Dictionary](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#populating-types-from-an-object-dictionary), covert each dictionary into a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` in the order that you want and serialize that.